# NotSerializableException occurs

Tags: java

```
public class move implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6696031872468154516L;
    public move(int a,int b){
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    int x,y;
}
```

I send this by ObjectOutputStream - just using out.writeObject(params[0]);

When I see LogCat, it says :

```
06-02 16:09:48.750: W/System.err(6060): java.io.NotSerializableException: com.SWAP.AndTablet.MainActivity
06-02 16:09:48.750: W/System.err(6060):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
06-02 16:09:48.750: W/System.err(6060):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
06-02 16:09:48.750: W/System.err(6060):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
06-02 16:09:48.750: W/System.err(6060):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
06-02 16:09:48.750: W/System.err(6060):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
06-02 16:09:48.750: W/System.err(6060):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
06-02 16:09:48.750: W/System.err(6060):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
06-02 16:09:48.750: W/System.err(6060):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
06-02 16:09:48.750: W/System.err(6060):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
06-02 16:09:48.754: W/System.err(6060):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
06-02 16:09:48.754: W/System.err(6060):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
06-02 16:09:48.754: W/System.err(6060):     at com.SWAP.AndTablet.MainActivity$MouseMoveSendTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:59)
06-02 16:09:48.754: W/System.err(6060):     at com.SWAP.AndTablet.MainActivity$MouseMoveSendTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-02 16:09:48.754: W/System.err(6060):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-02 16:09:48.754: W/System.err(6060):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-02 16:09:48.754: W/System.err(6060):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-02 16:09:48.754: W/System.err(6060):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-02 16:09:48.757: W/System.err(6060):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-02 16:09:48.757: W/System.err(6060):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect this is a nested class, which means there's an implicit reference to the outer class, even if you don't use it. So if your class is nested within `MainActivity`, you'll end up trying to serialize the enclosing instance of `MainActivity` even though you don't want to. `MainActivity` isn't serializable (and almost certainly shouldn't be) which is causing the error.

You can get round this just by making it static:

```
public static class Move implements Serializable {
    private final int x, y;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6696031872468154516L;

    public Move(int a,int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}
```

If it *isn't* a nested class, then I suspect the problem doesn't lie with the code you've shown us.

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me! I divided the two classes in each java file.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get the `java.io.NotSerializableException` exception error. Make sure you `implements Serializable` interface and **"define the variables as static"**